# Can we use "Chikai" for time?

Tags: words, time

I would want to say something like "exams are just round the corner." 
, is "Shiken mou chikai desu." acceptable?

Comment: Yes, you can use it for time as well.

Comment: 近いうちに is a common expression. Means something like 'soon' or 'near future' ([examples](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%BF%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB))

Answer (score 3):

Chikai 近い can be used for time definitely.

> 試験(が)もう近いです
>   Shiken(ga) mou chikai desu.

This is a totally acceptable expression, preferably with the particle 'ga'.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use 近い

But you can also use もうすぐ to better express the nuance of "just round the corner".

> もうすぐ{LLLL}試験です。